# ADFSv2.1 redirect infinite loop

Tags: adfs

I'm trying to setup an ADFS server in a lab to test out the federation authentication mechanism.

I'm following this guide:  http://www.syfuhs.net/post/2010/08/13/Installing-ADFS-2-and-Federating-an-Application.aspx up until the part when they create the web site, of course.

The test web site is a just a file->new proyect->mvc5 with organizational account, just as the official documentation states should be: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauthonprem

When I try this setup with azure ad, there is no problem and works beautifully, but with my ADFS, I get a redirect loop of 302 found ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoID5.jpg))

Up to my knowledge (which is very limited) everything is correctly configured on the ADFS and don't know how to even start to troubleshoot this. I've searched google and came to no response, also have a parallel stackoverflow question on this, but I thought maybe IT experts can give me more light on the subject.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**: Attempting to demonstrate minimal understanding, here we go.

I'm Using ADFS V2.1 on Windows Server 2012

What have I done: I tried setting the RP Endpoint as Ws-Federation (given that the new MVC5 Templates uses that technology) pointing the Url to my site. 
This had no impact on the observed behavior.

Tried using invalid credentials, with expected behavior: asks for credentials again and again until 403 is returned.

Setted up Azure AD just to test out the MVC5 configuration, with the same code, just changing the endpoint urls. Observed behavior: it works with no problem.

The patches suggested in the responses are not applicable to ADFS 2.1 (yes, I forgot to mention that detail >_<)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the looping behaviour occur after MS13-066 is installed.

Please ensure you have installed all the updates for AD FS correctly. This includes the latest AD FS 2.0 rollup 3 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2790338 and MS13-066 security update and the post MS13-66 hotfix to address issues with that update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896713.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using ADFS 2.1

Comment: The 2896713 does apply. If you are still having issues after the update, please update the thread.

Comment: In the summary of the hotfix it states that applies to Server 2012, but there is only downloads for windows 8, vista and 2008 r2. Will try the windows 8 download.

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same 302 redirect loop with ADFS 2.0 when using a Encryption certificate for the Relying Party I generated myself using makecert. In addition to the redirect in the browser ADFS 2.0 would log errors with Event ID 317 saying "An error occurred during an attempt to build the certificate chain..."

Since this was development, it was acceptable to turn off the check for this using PowerShell

```
Add-PSSpanin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName my.relyingparty.com -EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck None
```

This stopped the 302 redirect loop