# ADFS 2.1 redirect loop on login

Tags: windows-server-2012, adfs

I'm having a similar problem to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/561187/adfsv2-1-redirect-infinite-loop), using AD FS for SSO (2 ASP.NET sites and a handful of WCFs). On login, users hit a 302 redirect loop, although when the browser stops the loop and the user manually types in the site's URL, their login has completed successfully. I haven't been able to find a trigger for this behaviour, although [KB3003381](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-077) was recently applied to the system. I have been unable to reproduce this on our test system.

This issue is currently on a production system, so disabling the certificate checks is not an option. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/561494/213555) mentions [a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2896713), but when we applied this to our test system it actually **caused** the redirect loop to occur!

I'm running AD FS 2.1 on Server 2012. We also have SecurEnvoy providing 2FA.

Sorry for making a new question, but I don't have the rep here to comment. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have KB2843638/9, then you *must* use KB2896713.
You really do want to apply KB3003381, that is perfect.

Turning off the revocation and other checks on signing and encryption certificates is perfect. They were exchanged out-of-band, which makes the key a trusted key. Not checking is actually better :-), the cert is just a (bulky) interoperable transport container for the public key. Self signed is even better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I've got to wait for a maintenance window to put KB3003381 on, I'll let you know what happens...

Comment: I don't expect KB3003381 to help for the loop. But you do need it as a security fix. Do you have KB2896713? And what was the effect of disabling the certificate validation? Is your test environment not identical to production? That would save you a lot of waiting for maintenance windows.

Comment: Removing KB3003381 stops the loop from occurring. Should I be raising a bug with Microsoft at this point?

Comment: I cannot help you any further this way, because I have almost no information about your loop (applied patches etc.). Someone should take a look at it. Microsoft does offer that service, but 2008R2 is in extendend support (too old).